# All elements must have a set of attributes

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I need to make sure that all elements (whose names are not of interest) of an XML document contain a particular set of attributes.

But `xs:any` wouldn't allow this:

```
<xs:any processContents="lax">
  <xs:complexType>
     <xs:attribute name="count1" type="nonNegativeInteger" use="required"/>
     <xs:attribute name="count2" type="nonNegativeInteger" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:any>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSD cannot make such global statements about attribute usage.

For starters, `xs:any` has to appear in the content model of another, named element.  Then, once you declare that any element may occur using `xs:any`, you cannot constrain its attributes further via `xs:attribute` declarations.

In XSD 1.1, you could use `xs:assert` to state requirements regarding attributes on a particular element but not across the board for all elements.

If your XSD does have conventionally defined, named elements, you could use `xs:attributeGroup` to declare commonly used attributes and explicitly reference them in each element declaration.

Otherwise, consider XSLT, Schematron, or some other language instead of XSD for enforcing such a constraint.